# Regular expression: Distinguish between exponents like ² and regular numbers like 2

Tags: python, regex

In Python I'd like to distinguish between exponents like ² and regular numbers like 2.
I've got strings like

`mystrings = ['2something', 'something3', 'm²', 'pcs.']`

and I'd like to get rid of all normal numbers except the exponents. My current solution can't do that:

`[re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+\.?', mystring)[0] for mystring in mystrings]`

It returns ['something', 'something', 'm', 'pcs.'] but I'd like to get ['something', 'something', 'm²', 'pcs.'] as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub(r'\d+', '', mystring)` to remove "inline" digits, since ordinary digits are included into meta sequence `\d`, and exponents and such are not.

```py
import re 
mystrings = ['2something', 'something3', 'm²', 'pcs.']
vv = [re.sub(r'\d+', '', mystring) for mystring in mystrings]
print(vv)
# ['something', 'something', 'm²', 'pcs.']
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's built-in `re` doesn't support Unicode properties and whatnot yet, but the third-party library `regex` do:

```py
import regex

pattern = regex.compile(r'[a-zA-Z\p{No}]+\.?')
```

...in which `\p{No}` matches any characters in the [`Other_Number`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/No) category.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/MRKi5t/1).

This, however, will also match subscript digits and any non-zero-to-nine number. To avoid matching unwanted characters, you can specify all superscript digits in a `re`-compatible way:

```
[a-zA-Z\u00B2\u00B3\u00B9\u2070\u2074\u2075\u2076\u2077\u2078\u2079]+\.?
[a-zA-Z⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]+\.?
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/MRKi5t/2).